# コンテナからVScodeを起動したい(Ubuntu)

Tags: ubuntu, docker, vscode

タイトルの通りです。
私は下記の手順を踏みました。

1. コンテナAには、python3とVScodeなどをインストールし、commitでimage化する。
2. imageからコンテナを実行するために、以下のオプションをつけました。

   ```
   docker run -e DISPLAY=$DISPLAY -it -v /var/hoge:/var/hoge A_image /bin/bash
   ```
3. マウントしたディレクトリの中にあるtest.pyを開くためにディレクトリの移動。

   ```
   cd /var/hoge/
   ```
4. VS codeで開く

   ```
   code --user-data-dir test.py
   ```
5. 何も起こらない

・環境はホストとコンテナ共にUbuntuです。
・code と引数なしでも起動しません。
・ホストとコンテナどちらにもVScodeを入れましたが、理想はコンテナ上のVScodeで実行できることです。

Comment: ホスト環境もコンテナ環境も共に Ubuntu でしょうか？　環境の情報を「編集」から追記していただけませんでしょうか？

Comment: 質問者さんとおぼしき匿名ユーザーから編集提案を頂いていますが、質問者さんのアカウントであれば自由に追記できますので、お手数ですがログインして再度お試しくださいませ。

Comment: こんな記事があるようですが。[Dockerコンテナ内でVSCodeを起動する(Ubuntu)](https://qiita.com/kanosawa/items/0c83f8d8eaaa4a72e1cd)

Answer (score 0):

起動しない直接の原因かはわかりませんが、`--user-data-dir`オプションで指定するのは
**ディレクトリ(フォルダ)名**です。質問文では`test.py`という編集対象のファイル名を指定しているので、少なくともオプションの指定が間違っています。

[The Visual Studio Code command-line options](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/command-line)

> ```
> --user-data-dir <dir>
>
>   Specifies the directory that user data is kept in, useful when running as root.
> ```

Comment: code --user-data-dir='/var/hoge/'　もしくは、 code --user-data-dir /var/hoge/　と入力してみましたが何のアクションもありませんでした。

Comment: そもそも、何も引数を指定しない状態でVScodeは起動するのでしょうか？

Answer (score 0):

[cubick さんが指摘されている問題](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/56017/19110)のほかに、GUI を管理する X11 関係の設定も足りていません。`xhost` コマンドで接続を許可したり、`-v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix` オプションを付けたりする必要があるはずです。